# ssh command -N option explanations

Tags: ssh

In the following command :

```
ssh -L 2424:localhost:5212 myuser@mywebsite.com -N -p 8945
```

What `-N` mean/role ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man ssh`:

> `-N`      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.

So you won't get a remote shell. It will only open the forwarded tunnel.